# Where is the Bhajan "Shri Ramachandra Kripalu Bhajmana" found?

Tags: rama

I have recently seen a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOPawIIqsLg) on Shri Ramachandra bhajan which is very beautiful and emotional. So I want to know about this Bhajan.

Can you give where does this Bhajan found? And can you provides full writings of it, and about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devotional bhajan/aarti "Śrī Rāma Chandra Kṛipālu Bhajumana" is one of the most famous hymns devoted to Lord Rāma, composed by Gosvāmī Tulasīdāsa.

This bhajan is found in the book - "Vinaya Partika" (विनयपत्रिका), which is a collection of several short hymns devoted to various deities starting with Gaṇeśha, Sūrya, Śhiva, Devī, et al., but most part of the book is embellished with hymns to Śrī Rāma.

While the most famous of the Tulasīdāsa's works - the Ramcharitmanas is [categorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas#Works) into Avadhī composition. Vinaya Patrika is considered as a Braja composition. Directly quoting from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas#Other_major_works):

> Vinaya Patrika (विनयपत्रिका), literally Petition of Humility, is a Braja work consisting of 279 stanzas or hymns. The stanzas form a petition in the court of Rama asking for Bhakti. **It is considered to be the second best work of Tulsidas after the Ramcharitmanas,** and is regarded as important from the viewpoints of philosophy, erudition, and eulogistic and poetic style of Tulsidas. **The first 43 hymns are addressed to various deities and Rama's courtiers and attendants, and remaining are addressed to Rama.**

This particular bhajan - "Śrī Rāma Chandra Kṛipālu" also called - "Śrī Rāma Stuti" is written in the Vinay Patrika at verse number 45.

Giving here the Original verses, the transliterations, and both: Hindi and English translation here, [sourced from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shri_Ramachandra_Kripalu) Wikipedia:

> **Original version: In Sanskrit (संस्कृत)**
>
> ॥ श्रीरामचन्द्र कृपालु ॥
>
> श्री रामचन्द्र कृपालु भजुमन हरण भवभय दारुणं ।
>  नव कञ्ज लोचन कञ्ज मुख कर
> कञ्ज पद कञ्जारुणं ॥१॥
>  कन्दर्प अगणित अमित छवि नव नील नीरद सुन्दरं ।
> पटपीत मानहुँ तडित रुचि शुचि नौमि जनक सुतावरं ॥२॥
>  भजु दीनबन्धु दिनेश
> दानव दैत्य वंश निकन्दनं ।
>  रघुनन्द आनन्द कन्द कोसल चंद्र दशरथ नन्दनं
> ॥३॥
>  सिर मुकुट कुंडल तिलक चारु उदार अङ्ग विभूषणं ।
>  आजानु भुज शर चाप धर
> संग्राम जित खरदूषणं ॥४॥
>  इति वदति तुलसीदास शंकर शेष मुनि मन रंजनं ।
>  मम
> हृदय कंज निवास कुरु कामादि खलदल गंजनं ॥५॥
>  मनु जाहि राचेयु मिलहि सो वरु
> सहज सुन्दर सांवरो ।
>  करुणा निधान सुजान शीलु स्नेह जानत रावरो ॥६॥
>  एहि
> भांति गौरी असीस सुन सिय सहित हिय हरषित अली।
>  तुलसी भवानिहि पूजी
> पुनि-पुनि मुदित मन मन्दिर चली ॥७॥
>
> ॥सोरठा॥
> जानी गौरी अनुकूल सिय हिय हरषु न जाइ कहि ।
>  मंजुल मंगल मूल वाम अङ्ग फरकन लगे।

> **Transliteration: IAST**
>
> ॥ Shriramachandra Kripalu॥
>
> Śrīrāmacandra kr̥pālu bhajamana haraṇabhavabhayadāruṇaṁ ।
> Navakañjalocana kañjamukha karakañja padakañjāruṇaṁ  ।।1।।
>  Kandarpa
> agaṇita amita chavi navanīlanīradasundaraṁ ।
>  Paṭapītamānahu taḍita
> ruciśuci naumijanakasutāvaraṁ ।।2।।
>  Bhajadīnabandhu dinēśa
> dānavadaityavaṁśanikandanaṁ ।
>  Raghunanda ānandakanda kośalachandra
> daśarathanandanaṁ ।।3।।
>  Śiramukuṭakuṇḍala tilakacāru
> udāru'aṅgavibhūṣaṇaṁ ।
>  Ājānubhuja śaracāpadhara
> saṅgrāmajitakharadūṣaṇaṁ ।।4।।
>  Iti vadati tulasīdāsa
> śaṅkaraśeṣamunimanarañjanaṁ ।
>  Mamahr̥dayakañjanivāsakuru
> kāmādikhaladalagañajanaṁ ।।5।।
>  manu jāhi rāceyu milahi so varu sahaja sundara sāṁvaro ।
>  karuṇā nidhāna sujāna śīlu sneha jānata rāvaro ॥6॥
> ehi bhāṁti gaurī asīsa suna siya sahita hiya haraṣita alī।
>  tulasī bhavānihi pūjī puni-puni mudita mana mandira calī ॥7॥
>
> ॥soraṭhā॥ 
> jānī gaurī anukūla siya hiya haraṣu na jāi kahi ।
>  maṁjula maṁgala mūla vāma aṅga pharakana lage।

> **Hindi Translation**
>
> हे मन कृपालु श्रीरामचन्द्रजी का भजन कर । वे संसार के जन्म-मरण रूपी
> दारुण भय को दूर करने वाले हैं ।
>  उनके नेत्र नव-विकसित कमल के समान हैं ।
> मुख-हाथ और चरण भी लालकमल के सदृश हैं ॥१॥
> उनके सौन्दर्य की छ्टा अगणित
> कामदेवों से बढ़कर है । उनके शरीर का नवीन नील-सजल मेघ के जैसा सुन्दर
> वर्ण है ।
>  पीताम्बर मेघरूप शरीर मानो बिजली के समान चमक रहा है । ऐसे
> पावनरूप जानकीपति श्रीरामजी को मैं नमस्कार करता हूँ ॥२॥
>   हे मन दीनों के
> बन्धु, सूर्य के समान तेजस्वी, दानव और दैत्यों के वंश का समूल नाश करने
> वाले,
>  आनन्दकन्द कोशल-देशरूपी आकाश में निर्मल चन्द्रमा के समान
> दशरथनन्दन श्रीराम का भजन कर ॥३॥
>   जिनके मस्तक पर रत्नजड़ित मुकुट, कानों
> में कुण्डल भाल पर तिलक, और प्रत्येक अंग मे सुन्दर आभूषण सुशोभित हो रहे
> हैं । जिनकी भुजाएँ घुटनों तक लम्बी हैं । जो धनुष-बाण लिये हुए हैं,
> जिन्होनें संग्राम में खर-दूषण को जीत लिया है ॥४॥
>   जो शिव, शेष और
> मुनियों के मन को प्रसन्न करने वाले और काम, क्रोध, लोभादि शत्रुओं का
> नाश करने वाले हैं, तुलसीदास प्रार्थना करते हैं कि वे श्रीरघुनाथजी मेरे
> हृदय कमल में सदा निवास करें ॥५॥
>  
>   जिसमें तुम्हारा मन अनुरक्त हो गया है,
> वही स्वभाव से सुन्दर साँवला वर (श्रीरामचन्द्रजी) तुमको मिलेगा। वह जो
> दया का खजाना और सुजान (सर्वज्ञ) है, तुम्हारे शील और स्नेह को जानता है
> ॥६॥
>   इस प्रकार श्रीगौरीजी का आशीर्वाद सुनकर जानकीजी समेत सभी सखियाँ
> हृदय मे हर्षित हुईं। तुलसीदासजी कहते हैं, भवानीजी को बार-बार पूजकर
> सीताजी प्रसन्न मन से राजमहल को लौट चलीं ॥७॥ 
> ॥सोरठा॥
>  गौरीजी को अनुकूल
> जानकर सीताजी के हृदय में जो हर्ष हुआ वह कहा नही जा सकता। सुन्दर मंगलों
> के मूल उनके बाँये अंग फड़कने लगे ॥

> #### English Translation
>
> O mind! Revere the benign Shri Ramachandra, who removes 'Bhava' the
> worldly sorrow or pain, 'Bhaya' the fear, and 'Daruna' the scarcity or
> poverty. Who has fresh lotus eyes, lotus face and lotus hands, feet
> like lotus and like the rising sun. ॥1॥
>  His beauty exceeds innumerable
> Kaamdevas (Cupids). He is like a newly formed beautiful blue cloud. The
> yellow robe on his body appears like delightful lighting. He is the
> consort of the daughter of Sri Janak (Sri Sita), the embodiment of
> sacredness.॥2॥
>  O mind, sing praises of Sri Ram, a friend of the poor.
> He is the lord of the solar dynasty. He is the destroyer of demons and
> devils and their race. The descendant of Sri Raghu is the source of
> joy, a moon of his mother Kaushalya and he is the son of Sri
> Dashrath.॥3॥
>  He wears a crown on his head, pendants on his ear, and
> tilak (crimson mark) on his forehead. All his organs are beautiful and
> well decorated with ornaments. His arms reach his knees. He holds a
> bow and an arrow. He emerged victorious in the battle with demons Khar
> and Dushan.॥4॥
>  Thus says Sri Tulasīdāsa – O Śrī Rāma, the charmer of Lord
> Śhiv, Śrī Śheṣa and saints, reside in the lotus of my heart and
> destroy all the evils and their associates like desires.॥5॥
> In which your mind has become attached, you will get the same beautiful man (Śrī RāmaChandraji) by nature. He who is the treasure of mercy and the omniscient (omniscient), knows your modesty and affection.॥6॥
>  Thus listening to the blessings of Shri Gauriji, all the friends including Jankiji
> Rejoiced in heart. Tulasīdāsaji says, by worshiping Bhavānī again and again
> Sītāji returned to the palace with a happy heart.॥7॥
> ॥soraṭhā॥
> The joy that  Sītāji's heart felt after assurance from devī Gaurī as favorable cannot be said. The Happiness experienced by Sītāji's heart thus knew no bounds.

One may read the Gita Press based Original Sanskrit verse and their Hindi translations from the [Arhive links here](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookVinayPatrikaByGitaPress/page/n59/mode/2up).

---

Other Sources to Refer further on Tulasīdāsajī and his works:

- [A Brief Biography of Gosvāmī Tulasīdāsa](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Tulsidas)
- [Complete Works of Gosvami Tulsidas by Prachya Prakashan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Complete_Works_of_Gosvami_Tulsidas_Vinay/ppshAAAAMAAJ?kptab=editions&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyxefuuvjwAhWHxjgGHdobCTsQmBYwAHoECAUQBw)
- [The Arhive Meta on compositions by Gosvāmī Tulasīdāsa](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%28%28subject%3A%22Tulsidas%22%20OR%20creator%3A%22Tulsidas%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Tulsidas%22%20OR%20title%3A%22Tulsidas%22%29%20OR%20%28%221532-1623%22%20AND%20Tulsidas%29%29%20AND%20%28-mediatype:software%29)

Comment: Hi Vivikta, this happens to be one of my favorite Sri Ram Bhajans. But I was confused to see chaupai 6, 7 and the soratha. According to me, they appear after the Gauri Stuti in the Ramcharitmanas. 

Jai Jai Girivar Rajakisori, Jai Mahesa Mukha Chand Chakori,
Jai Gajabadana Shadanana Mata, Jagata Janani Damini Duti Gata

This continues upto Suno Siya Satya Ashis Humari, Poojahi Manokamana Tumhari, Narada Bachana Sada Suchi Sacha, So Baru Milihi Jaahi Manuracha.

After this comes Manu Jaahi Racheo Milihi Sobaru ........ upto Manjul Mangal Mool Baam Ang Pharakan Lage. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, yes @curiousseeker You're right. However, in all the "*puja books*", these days, this is the standard recension we get by all major publications . Thus I appended it this way only.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!